# How to make 'www.site.com/contact.php' to be 'www.site.com/contact/' ?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Looking for some help with my .htaccess file and mod-rewrite.

I want to make my URLs more friendly.

I would like to take my URLS from:

```
www.site.com/contact.php
```

to:

```
www.site.com/contact/
```

Any help would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already mentioned, you need to add an entry to the htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contact /contact.php
```

Or if you want to do this to all of your php pages then just modify it as following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Would you need to do this for all the .php pages? Or is there a way around that does it for all pages?